# Atoms of a sigma algebra

Tags: probability, sigma-algebra

I've been reading Schilling's *Measures, Integrals, and Martingales*, and I ran across a remark (on page 21) that I don't understand.

Here is the setup: let $A_{1},\ldots,A_{n}$ be non-empty, disjoint subsets of $X$ with $\bigcup_{k=1}^n A_{k}=X$.  Schilling says that "a set $A$ in a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathscr{A}$ is called an atom, if there is no proper subset $\emptyset\neq B \subsetneq A  $ such that $B \in \mathscr{A}$.  In this sense all $A_{k}$ are atoms [of the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $A_{1},\ldots,A_{n}]$."

Why are the $A_{k}$ atoms?  This seems intuitive, but I don't see how to prove it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since $A_i$ are disjoint and their union is the entire space $\mathcal{X}$, clearly you cannot construct a set $B$ such that $B$ is a strict subset of any $A_i$ using complimentation or union.

Since no such set can be constructed, it immediately follows that the $\sigma$-algebra generated by them, defined as containing any set that can be expressed as a countable union or compliment of these $A_i$, cannot contain a strict subset of any $A_i$. For if it could, that would contradict the observation in the prior paragraph. Hence all $A_i$ are atoms of the given sigma algebra.

To see why no strict subset can be constructed, draw a diagram of a space and partition it into disjoint parts. It should be clear you cannot construct a strict subset of any the parts using the others (though you *can* construct any $A_i$ itself by complimenting the union of all other $A_j, j \neq i$.

If such a strict subset could be constructed, it would imply that some $x \in A_i$ also belongs to another $A_j$, contradicting the disjoint property of $A_i$'s.

Comment: Thanks, Xiaomi.  That's along the lines of what I was thinking.  Another approach that I thought of is to first show that any element of the $\sigma$-algebra must either be the empty set or a union of some of the $A_i$.  (This is mostly just definition-chasing, but also requires, I think, an appeal to the fact that the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the $A_i$ is the *minimal* $\sigma$-algebra containing the $A_i$.)  It then follows immediately that the $A_i$'s are atoms.

Comment: This argument would extend to an arbitrary partition of $X$, not just a finite partition $A_1,\ldots,A_n$. Right?

Comment: @James I am not sure if Xiaomi's argument can be extended (I don't think his proof is rigorous enough).  But the conclusion does hold for *countable* partition (see my answer below).  I am also not sure if it holds for uncountable partition (in the first place, is it conventional to define a "uncountable partition" for a general sample space? -- I seem never encountered such a concept).

Answer (score 3):

The statement can be extended to the case that the *countable* partition $\mathscr{A} := \{A_1, A_2, \ldots\}$ of $X$.

Let $\mathscr{G}$ consist of all the unions of the $A_i$ (plus $\varnothing$). Then $\mathscr{G}$ itself is a $\sigma$-field, because

1. $\varnothing \in \mathscr{G}$.
2. $\mathscr{G}$ is closed under the formation of complementation:  if $G \in \mathscr{G}$, then $G = \cup_{i \in I}A_i$ for some (finite or countably many) index set $I \subset \mathbb{Z}^+$.  It then follows that $G^c = \cup_{i \in I^c} A_i$, which is clearly also in $\mathscr{G}$.  Note that this is one place where we used the condition that $\mathscr{A}$ is a partition of $X$.
3. $\mathscr{G}$ is closed under the formation of countable unions:  if $G_k = \cup_{i \in I_k}A_i \in \mathscr{G}$, then
   $$\bigcup_k G_k = \bigcup_k \bigcup_{i \in I_k}A_i = \bigcup_{i \in \cup_k I_k} A_i \in \mathscr{G}.$$

The fact that $\mathscr{G}$ is a $\sigma$-field (which we just proved) containing $\mathscr{A}$ (trivial) then implies that $\sigma(\mathscr{A}) \subset \mathscr{G}$ (in fact, $\sigma(\mathscr{A}) = \mathscr{G}$), which can be used to show the conclusion: for each $n$, if $\varnothing \neq A \subsetneq A_n$ is a $\sigma(\mathscr{A})$-set, it then follows by $\sigma(\mathscr{A}) \subset \mathscr{G}$ that $A$ must also be a $\mathscr{G}$-set, that is $A$ is a union of some $A_i$s, which is impossible (because $A \cap A_i = \varnothing$ for all $i \neq n$ and $A \neq A_n$ -- this is the second place where we used the condition that $\mathscr{A}$ is a partition of $X$).  This completes the proof.

Note that the condition that $A_1, A_2, \ldots$ are disjoint is crucial for the statement to hold.  When $A_1, A_2, \ldots$ are not necessarily disjoint, then $A_n$ could not be an atom.  For example, the Borel $\sigma$-field $\mathscr{B}(0, 1]$ can be countably generated by intervals with rational end points, but clearly the Borel set $(0, 1/2]$ is not an atom, for $(1/4, 1/2]$ is a proper subset of it, and $(1/4, 1/2]$ is also a Borel set.